# $\frac{1}{2}<\sigma<1$, is $f(n) = \Bigl| \,1+ \frac{1}{2^{\sigma + i n}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n^{\sigma + i n}} \Bigr|$ from $O(\log n)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, inequalities, l-functions

We have $\frac{1}{2} < \sigma < 1$ and
$$
f(n) = \Bigl|\, 1+ \frac{1}{2^{\sigma + i n}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n^{\sigma + i n}} \Bigr|
$$
. My goal is proving this statement that $|f(n)|$ is $O(\log n)$ but I'm not certain that this is true. some bounds like $O(n^{1-\sigma})$ are simple to prove but my desired bound is $\log n$.

Any help?

Comment: This is equivalent asking for the bound $\zeta(\sigma+it) = O( \log t )$ for integer values of $t$, which is basically a variant of the Lindelof hypothesis.

Comment: Actually, from looking at Montgomery's paper http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=460255 it seems that the bound $\zeta(\sigma+it) = O(\log t)$ cannot hold for all sufficiently large $t$; presumably the argument can extend to the case when $t$ is restricted to be integer.

Comment: However, mean value theorems will show that the desired bound is true for "most" values of n.  See e.g. Titchmarsh's book on the zeta function.

Comment: Thanks @TerryTao. I have a question: Have you noticed that I want to have the logarithmic order just on a fixed vertical line which is in the right of the critical line $Re(s) = 0.5$, not on the whole of the critical strip or on the critical line? (According to that which the Lindelof Hypothesis is for the growth of zeta on the critical line)

Comment: The growth of zeta (after deleting the pole at s=1) on the critical line is related to the growth on other lines by Lindelof's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f%27s_theorem .  Note also that Montgomery's paper cited above also applies to lines to the right of the critical line.